# Connect a point with an already existing line

Tags: matlab, line, matlab-figure

I have a line created by two points (A and B) and then a third point (C). I want to connect (make a line between C and the line created by A-B but I don't know how to do it and I have not being able to find the answer. I have attached a little graph so it is better understood.

[image: Visualization of my question]

Comment: This is more of a mathematics problem than a programming one as things stand. Use your favourite search engine to search for "Find perpendicular line to a line", which is an easy two-line equation. That line will have a free parameter, which you can fit using your point C. Then try to program that and [edit] the question once you get stuck on a programming problem.

Answer (score 1):

The equation of the line is clearly `y = (5x - 1)/3` from the two known points `A` and `B`. Then, since you want to find a point `D` on line AB programmatically such that CD is normal to AB, you can find the distances between point `C` and all points on line AB and choose `D` with the minimum distance. So, you could calculate the squared distances by `d = (x - Cx)^2 + (y - Cy)^2` and select the minimum.

```
Ax = 2; Bx = 5;
Ay = 3; By = 8;
plot([Ax Bx], [Ay By], 'LineWidth', 1)
hold on

Cx = 4; Cy = 4;                % point C coordinates 
x = linspace(2,5,1000);        % 1000 points on AB
y = (5*x - 1)/3;               % AB line equation
d = (x - Cx).^2 + (y - Cy).^2; % distance from C to points on AB
[~, ind] = min(d);             % min distance index gives point D on AB

Dx = x(ind); Dy = y(ind);
plot([Cx Dx], [Cy Dy], 'LineWidth', 1)
axis equal
```

[image]

Mathematically, you can find `D` as follows. The slope of line AB is `5/3`, which means the slope of CD will be `-3/5`. Using point `C` on CD, we can find the equation of CD to be `y = (-3x + 32)/5`. Finally, solve the two equations to find point `D`.

```
syms x
Dx = solve( (5*x - 1) / 3 - (-3*x + 32) / 5 )
```

This gives `Dx = 101/34`, then substitute into CD equation to get `y = 157/34`. The programmatic solution is close to the exact analytical solution.